# Directory mounted on a newly created logical volume does not show a correct size

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, centos7, diskmanagement

I have two physical hard drives on a Linux system (server / hosting), and I created a logical volume from sda3 (partition on disk A) and sdb (the whole disk B). I then mounted it on /home directory, and when I enter:

```
du -sh /home
```

...this is showing a size of 20K, and it should be around 3.6TB in size. When I enter:

```
lsblk
```

...I get the correct values. So I am assuming that the size is right, but it just does not show with this command, for some reason. I was reading about resize2fs command, but I am not sure if this is what I would need here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confused between `du` which shows how much space is used by files and `df` which shows the space (total, used and free) in a filesystem. Try `df -h /home`.

Comment: Note: `du`  = **d**isk **u**sage and `df` = **d**isk **f**ree.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try using df -hT, which shows the disk free space instead of du (which is used to know how much space a directory and subfolders are using currently).

Also, df -hT will show you the total disk space from all partitions mounted on your system.